# Simple login system UserController

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication

I have the following:

a login route in app.js that sets success: false if invalid password or username.

but for some reason in the actual login html the authentication process is completely ignored.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an href. You need to have a button of a submit type to submit the form.

Change your `<div class="form-login" ng-submit="login()">` line to:
`<form class="form-login" ng-submit="login()">`. That will tell Angular this is a form. Then, change your closing `</div>` to `</form>` as well.

```
<span class="group-btn">     
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">
    login <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>
  </button>
</span>
```

Comment: Using this doesn't let me log in at all now. The user also doesn't print to the console when I do console.log($scope.user);

Comment: What if you change your function to `$scope.login = function(){ console.log($scope.user) }`? You aren't getting any errors at all?

Comment: Well I've been getting the error TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'settings.keyValue.charCodeAt') for a while now, not sure if it's related to this.

Comment: I would say not. If you add more code maybe we can help more. What does your full controller/template look like?

Comment: I updated, did not notice you had `<div>` vs. `<form>`. You'd want to use ng-submit on a form.

Comment: What happens if you remove window.location and just `console.log(response)`?

Comment: That was my fault really, sorry. Okay so it prints the user to the console but the authentication still isn't happening. Is my $scope.login correct? Does my code imply that it only goes to '#/add_event' if the login success==true?

Comment: data: {message: "This user does not exist.", success: false} for an unsuccessful login. {data: {success: true, message: "Successful Login!", token: etc. for successful

Comment: Solved it with if(response.data.success). Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)

Comment: I would take a look here as well, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http. That will show how to capture errors, etc. `.success` will go away if you decide to upgrade your angular version.